# How to create a chart with a variable number of lines based on the data loaded via chart.dataSource.url

Tags: amcharts

I have a chart with some data loaded through an ajax request through

```
chart.dataSource.url = "...my url...";
```

It works as long as i specify every line i want to draw like this.

```
var chartLine1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
chartLine1.dataFields.valueY = "pies_eaten";
chartLine1.dataFields.dateX = "date";
```

But i have a variable number of lines based on the results of the dataSource load.
Is it possible to get the data array/object before the chart renders or to get amCharts to create one line for field?

Comment: Can you please share some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out our guide on [manipulating external data](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/loading-external-data/#Manipulating_loaded_data). Using the `dataSource`'s `"parseended"` event, you can manipulate the `data` directly or by re-assigning it before it gets passed off to the chart for consumption.

E.g. our [demo on using JSON `dataSource`](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/pVRjGG) has data from 2004-2012, we can just pass a new array to the `dataSource`'s `data`:

```js
chart.dataSource.events.on("parseended", function(event) {
  // Original demo originally has 19 data items, ranging from 1994 through 2012,
  // this should set it to 1999 through 2008:
  event.target.data = event.target.data.slice(5,15);
});
```

With the above, it'll show a line from 1999 through 2008:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/6a0026c6cc01406db3a178bd6dd3f931